# Any Phrases About Trees Growing From Peoples Graves?

Tags: word-requests, phrase

I'm looking for any phrases (成语/俗语/谚语, 等) that talk about the meaning of tress growing out of graves/tombs/resting places (of the dead).

Apparently having a tree growing out of someones grave is  supposed to be good thing for their offspring - just wondering if there are any phrases that talk about this.

Comment: 庭有枇杷树，吾妻死之年手所植，今已亭亭如盖矣。——《项脊轩志》。 Not strictly satisfying the condition, but a beautiful one.

Comment: @Jason nice one

Comment: @Jason That's a beautiful one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find 成语, and they're not very good meaning

> 墓木已拱\墓木拱矣 
>  ﻿[mù mù yǐ gǒng] 
>  【发音】mù mù yǐ gǒng
>   【解释】坟墓上的树木已有两手合抱那么粗了。意思是你快要死了。这是骂人的话。后指人死了很久。
>   【出处】《左传·僖公三十二年》：“尔何知？中寿，尔墓之木拱亦。”

Comment: Well good for the offspring not for try person themselves...Does fit the criteria though

Answer (score 1):

《周礼·冢人》疏，引《春秋纬》:

天子坟高三仞, 树以松; 诸侯半之, 树以柏; 大夫八尺, 树以药草; 士四尺, 树以槐。

This was the ancient regulations of tomb sizes and grave-tree species for different classes of the society.

Answer (score 0):

沉舟侧畔千帆过，病树前头万木春。选自唐代刘禹锡的《酬乐天扬州初逢席上见赠》
原意为翻覆的船只旁仍有千千万万的帆船经过；枯萎树木的前面也有万千林木欣欣向荣。运用比喻，借用自然景物的变化暗示社会的发展，蕴涵哲理。现多指新生事物必然战胜旧事物。 
Original intention is overturned boats sailing through the side still have thousands on thousands of trees have withered; in front of thousands of trees thriving. The use of metaphor, borrow natural scenery changes suggests that the development of the society, contain philosophy. It refers to the new thing must overcome old things.